# Blackberry cocos2d-x build error- libtiff.a warning: relocation in readonly section `.text'

Tags: blackberry, cocos2d-x, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, momentics

I have resolved a lot of linker errors and set up the SDK,NDk for blackberry. But now I am stuck with this linker error popping up everytime i build any project to the simulator. 
I tried to change permissions of .a file, but no luck. Also if I proceed the app will crash.Please help.

[image: Screenshot of the bug reported]